# android.gesture imports cannot be resolved...how to fix this?

Tags: android, gesture

This is regarding the sample included in the android sdk "GestureBuilder"

I think it needs the Android 1.5 API files, which I have downloaded using the SDK manager...
Still it is unable to find it..

Where to get android.gesture imports, as in which SDK are they present in ?

I see a lot of errors, most of them are due to the problem with the import (It is not importing the required files :-
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.Gesture;

Pls help :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean to tell that those imports here do not work:

```
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.gesture.GestureLibraries;
import android.gesture.GestureLibrary;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener;
```

If so, take a look at [this tut](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/creating-gestures/) and try implementing it in your App. If something goes wrong get back here with the LogCat output and put some code in that post.

**EDIT:**

Sorry about that, to answer to your question:

> Gestures API (android.gesture) was introduced in Android 1.6, lets you
>   store, load, draw and recognize gestures. In order to use Gestures
>   API, you need a prerecorded gestures library. The Android 1.6 SDK (or
>   later) comes with a new application pre-installed on the emulator,
>   called Gestures Builder. You can use this application to create a set
>   of pre-defined gestures for your own application.

Here's also a simpler [tut](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/09/gestures-builder-create-your-gestures.html), which explains how this works with a basic example.

Comment: That tut is really confusing.. "Copy the gesture library from the SD card" ...what ?

Comment: It doesn't mention how to get the gesture thing to work...but says it should look like this ...  "<some code> "....didn't help :/

Comment: What's your minSDK in the `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: The code is inside `/<android-sdk-linux>/samples/<platform>/GestureBuilder`, if you're searching for it.